# Compare Get-WmiObject (Date) Results

Tags: powershell, compare, wmi

I have a PowerShell script that will pull warranty information from an API and save it to a custom WMI Class.

I'm then bringing that data into our RMM tool, so that it will sync with our PSA solution, automating/updating warranty end-dates for renewals.

What I did not take into consideration at the time was: multiple warranties with the same property values.  Thus, rendering my caveman script of pulling values `where otherValue='specific text'` largely ineffective.

So, the WMI Class will have an instance per warranty, with the following properties:

```
ComputerName: SUMGAIZPC
EndDate: DD/MM/YYYY
ItemNumber: 000-0000
Model: PewterPro 2000
ServiceLevelDescription: When We Get To It
ServiceProvider: LOL
ServiceTag: 1FSD51L;K
StartDate: DD/MM/YYYY
```

So I hammered out something close to this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\Namespace -Class Warranty_Info |
    Where-Object ServiceLevelDescription -eq "How About Right Now" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty EndDate
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\Namespace -Class Warranty_Info |
    Where-Object ServiceLevelDescritpion -eq "When We Get To It" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty EndDate
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\Namespace -Class Warranty_Info |
    Where-Object ServiceLevelDescription -eq "You're Not Gonna Like It" |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty EndDate
```

The kicker is, that each of those commands are actually part of a script that is run by our RMM tool (LabTech, for those familiar), and is run by their PowerShell wrapper, so each command is run individually, and then stores the results in a variable called `%powershellresults%`.  I then set the values for the data fields within the RMM tool as the respective `%powershellresults%`.

Now, for the problem.  Sometimes, a warranty has been renewed.  So, when I get the info from the API, two instances are created with the same `ServiceLevelDescription`, but two totally different `EndDate` values. Which returns `12/15/2009 02/04/1974` to the data field, instead of just `12/15/2009`.  And since the field will be syncing up with a date field in our PSA (just the one), I need just one date.

Ultimately, I'll need to compare all of the data fields (for each different type of warranty) to determine which date gets to go the big-time, but that's another problem for another day.

If required I can provide any/all scripts I currently have (about 5 or 6).

Comment: Hi, if you could, how would you choose between the dates you get ? The oldest or the newest one ?

Comment: What is the data type of `EndDate`? Is it `DateTime` or `String`? (check with `... | %{$_.GetType().FullName}`)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - it's a string coming from the API, but it comes as yyyy-MM-dd, so I convert it using DateTime to MM-dd-yyyy. I will check and see if it's stored that way.  #sodawillow - I'm looking for the newest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give it a try, by `sort`ing on the `EndDate` field and `select`ing only the first instance returned.

If you need the oldest date, you could try this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\Namespace -Class Warranty_Info |
    Where-Object ServiceLevelDescription -eq "You're Not Gonna Like It" |
    Sort-Object EndDate |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty EndDate
```

As for the newest:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\Namespace -Class Warranty_Info |
    Where-Object ServiceLevelDescription -eq "You're Not Gonna Like It" |
    Sort-Object EndDate -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty EndDate
```

*Formatting tip: select code, hit Ctrl + K ^_^*

Edit : then, if you need to compare the dates for each type of warranty, you can store each of the WMI call returns in a separate variable, and compare them.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this! I'm going to test it out right now, to make sure I don't dumb it up, and still have the presence of mind to come back here and sing your praises :)

Comment: That's an option, yes.

Comment: Well, it took forever (that's what I get for trying to remote on to my work PC from a laptop at a campsite!), but it's been confirmed!  sodawillow is my hero with a brain I can only imagine is the size of a stadium!  Holy crap.  I can't thank you enough!